# How to convert a Roman value to integer in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, roman-numerals

I have say MDCCCLXXXVIII which is 1888 in Arabic number or D in Roman is 500 in Arabic or MIV is 1004, etc.

In a single TQL Query how can this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageNewDownload.aspx?Session=6B2F657966736B557872513D206A49674277435A774B314D6F6B4A67497A78415037773D3D) set of UDF functions (see UDFs_Transact-SQL.zip). There is ROMANTOARAB function there that allows you to do this:

```
select ROMANTOARAB('MDCCCLXXXVIII') -- Displays 1888
```

**Edit**: Looks like the original Url has stopped working for some reason.. Luckily, I have that ZIP on my hard drive and just put it on Dropbox - you can download [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12157243/Stackoverflow/UDFs_Transact-SQL.zip).

Comment: That's fine... what I am looking is a pure set based query

Comment: What do you mean by 'pure query'? The T-SQL doesn't support the conversion you're looking for so you'll need to bring a custom and quite complex t-sql code anyway. If you'd like I could post a source code of that function in the answer but it's fairly heavy.